# How to create shortcut between Onedrive synced SharePoint folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

My team recently migrated to SharePoint, away from VPN and servers. The main reason is the VPN issue with home internet.

We moved all files to SharePoint, so we can work without needing VPN all the time.

In the past, people created various shortcuts between folders in the server. When we moved to SharePoint, these shortcuts stopped working. Understandable, because the path is referencing to the server.

To mimic the VPN+server experience, everyone is using OneDrive sync + SharePoint.

My question is the following:
Is there a way to create shortcuts in the onedrive synced folders, and everyone can use them at their own PC.

The old method was creating a shortcut (send a shortcut to desktop, and move them to the server folders). With the same drive label at everyone's PC, it worked.
The SharePoint synced folder is placed under everyone's user folder C/USER/USER_NAME/SharePoint. This is problematic because each PC would have its own USER_NAME.

Any suggestions or alternatives are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We could create shortcuts in the OneDrive synced folders as follows:

[image]

You could also share the folders in your OneDrive for Business library with other people in your company,after sharing, the shared folders will appear in Shared with me in their OneDrive for Business library.

[image]